# Hive installed but giving error when running

Tags: apache, ubuntu, hadoop, installation, hive

I have installed HIVE using [this](http://doctuts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hive.html) tutorial. But when I run the folowing commad

`hive`

I get this error

`SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-2.0.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/lib/hive-common-2.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
Thu Mar 31 13:11:06 IST 2016 Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Permission denied)
Thu Mar 31 13:11:06 IST 2016 Thread[main,5,main] Cleanup action starting
ERROR XBM0H: Directory /usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/metastore_db cannot be created.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService.createServiceRoot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)`

and many other exceptions.

**EDIT 1 Cannot find hive-site.xml**

This is what my conf folder looks like  http://postimg.org/image/vloi2vneh/

**EDIT 2** ans wer to this question is not below but in chats because it is very long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it appears in the output message , you are using local metastore Derby database, and by default its location is `/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/metastore_db`, but apparently you do not have the permission to write on that directory

You should change the metastore directory to some location where you have the write permission.

To change the location of metastore directory, in `hive-site.xml` add (or modifiy) the following property:

```
<property>
   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
   <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/PATH/TO/NEW/METASTORE/DIR/metastore_db;create=true</value>
   <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

If you do not have the permission to change `hive-site.xml`, you could put hive-site.xml in a directory for example `$HOME/hive-config`, you could start by copying the default hive-site.xml , and then modify it. Then start hive as:

```
$ cp /usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-2.0.0-bin/conf/hive-default.xml.template $HOME/hive-config/hive-site.xml
###Modify the new hive-site.xml as mentioned above, then:
$hive --config $HOME/hive-config/
```

Comment: I dont want to use derby instead I want to use HBASE so should I first install HBASE then rectify this error?

Comment: I think I ve misexplained. Derby is your metastore, where you have the metadata about your Hive tables, it has nothing to do with the actual data you want to work with. Metastore database could be either Derby or one of: MySQL, Postgres,  Oracle, or MS SQL Server https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin#AdminManualMetastoreAdmin-SupportedBackendDatabasesforMetastore

Comment: For using Hive with HBase data, it is another question :) you could for a start have a look here (but of course you need your problem to be solved for :) ) : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration . The error you have is not related to HBase, but of course you need to install some client library to make hive connectivity with  HBase

Comment: i cant find file named hive-site.xml instead i found a file having name proto-hive-site.xml. and it has the following contents `<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://DBHOSTNAME/hivemetastoredb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>`   
Am I going right?

Comment: I cant see hive-site.xml in my conf folder. I have edited by question to show what all files I can see in my conf folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107830/discussion-between-user1314742-and-legendary-hunter).